# How to re-render a child component when new data arrives from the parent

Tags: angular, primeng

I've following code. Parent is sending some data to the child component using `@Input` directive:

**Parent HTML**

```
<div>
  <my-timeline
   [data]="data">
  </my-timeline>
</div>
```

In Parent TS there is a service that provides data to `data`

**Parent TS**

```
data=[];
...
this.service.getData().subscribe(res => {
  res.map(item=>{
    this.data.push({
      ...
     });
   })
})
```

And the child is receiving it as

**Child TS**

```
@Input data;
eventArray=[];

ngOnInit() {
  console.log("called"); // called only for the first time
  createTimeline(data[0].id); // called only for the first time
}

createTimeline(id) { // called only for the first time
  this.eventArray.push(.....)
}
```

**Child HTML**

```
<p-timeline [value]="eventArray">
...
</p-timeline>
```

The problem is that the `p-timeline` continues to show old events i.e. the events it loaded for the very first time. Because with subsequent data change from the Parent it is not causing ngOnIt in child to run. That is why `createTimeline` was never called again. Please pitch in.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to detect changes to an @Input property you can implement one of the following:

1. **Setter -** Implement the @Input() property as getter and setter, something like this:

```
 private _data: any;

  @Input()
  set data(value: any) {
    this._data= value;
   if(this._data)
     this.createTimeline(this._data[0].id)
  }

  get data(): any{
    return this._data;
  }
```

2. **OnChanges** lifecycle hook -

   First, lets explain what is `OnChanges` hook?

   From [Angular.io](https://angular.io/api/core/OnChanges):

   > OnChanges is a lifecycle hook that is called when any data-bound property
   > of a directive changes. Define an ngOnChanges() method to handle the
   > changes.

Lets implement the OnChanges lifecycle hook, something like this:

```
@Component({...})
export class SelectedPlayerComponent implements OnChanges {
  @Input() data;

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    if(changes.data)
    {
       this.createTimeline(changes.data.currentValue[0].id);//the new value that's changed
    }
 
  }
}
```

Thanks for Todd Motto good article about [detect input changes in angular](https://ultimatecourses.com/blog/detect-input-property-changes-ngonchanges-setters)

Answer (score 1):

Use `ChangeDetectionStrategy.Default` on all your components or use immutable data approach e.g

```js
this.data = [...this.data, {//item}];
```

Can read up on it in the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/change-detection-skipping-subtrees), along with how Angular `ngOnInit` works